# How can I use "map" and datetime.strptime with a dataframe to improve performance over "apply"?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

For the following code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    old_date = row['olddate']
    df.loc[index, 'date'] = datetime.strptime(old_date, "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

I am able to gain runtime performance by using lambdas (roughly a factor 10):

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['olddate'], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d"), axis=1)
```

According to https://github.com/sversh/pycon2017-optimizing-pandas I can expect further optimisation, if I use the `map` function: `map(function, arguments)`

How would it be possible to apply `strptime` to the `map` function?

Comment: could you point out where did you see he mentioned `map` offering better performance than `apply`?  furthermore, can you give us some sample data? it looks like you have rows of dates only. lastly, `map` is a method on Series, the dataframe equivalent would be `applymap` in order to apply function to each element.  I am not sure if map is going to optimise the performance here.

Comment: the performance increase is here: https://github.com/sversh/pycon2017-optimizing-pandas/blob/master/PyCon%20un-sad%20Pandas.ipynb - look for: `In [73]:` Regarding sample data: I have other columns in the dataframe, but that should not matter, should it? I clarified the question, that I refer to `map(function, arguments)`

Comment: `73` printed this: `%timeit df['distance'] = haversine(40.671, -73.985, df['latitude'], df['longitude'])`, that's vectorization, I guess what you referred to was `58`? Haversine used map function. have you read his pdf document? if not I would highly suggest you have a read. Haversine is the example function that he's demonstrating the performance techniques with. i.e. using `iterrows`, `apply`, `vectorization`, `np.arrays` and finally with `Cython` codes, these are the techniques that give you performance optimisation.